# How to split up arrays in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I want to split up 2 arrays as done in the following postgresql query:

```
SELECT
    main.ref_value_list_array_mitsi[ array_position(main.ref_name_list_array_mitsi,'BUDFPAYDATE') ] AS Debit_order_1_date,
    main.ref_value_list_array_mitsi[ array_position(main.ref_name_list_array_mitsi,'BUDFQUOTEDREHAB') ] AS Debit_order_1_total,
    owning_obj

FROM
    (
        SELECT
            owning_obj,
            string_to_array( ref_valuelist, CHR(27) ) AS ref_value_list_array_mitsi,
            string_to_array( UPPER(ref_namelist),',' ) AS ref_name_list_array_mitsi

        FROM
            ods.mit_system_index
```

How would I go about doing the same in SQL server?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a built-in `array`-type unlike Postgres, so this will be non-trivial. You may need to completely rethink your question.

Comment: Array's don't exist in SQL Server. There is no data type to hold them.

Comment: Please post your `CREATE TABLE` statement for `ods.mit_system_index`.

Comment: Depending on your SQL Server version you may be able to use [`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or  [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to split your array, e.g. `SELECT j.[Key], j.[Value] FROM OPENJSON('["Val 1","val 2","Val 3","Another Val","Something Else"]') AS j` will return 5 rows, one for each of the values in the array.

Comment: CREATE TABLE ods.mit_system_index
(
  rem_namelist character varying,
  rem_expression character varying,
  ref_namelist character varying,
  ref_labellist character varying,
  ref_mandatorylist character varying,
  ref_datatypelist character varying,
  ref_controltypelist character varying,
  ref_sizelist character varying,
  ref_hiddenlist character varying,
  ref_additionalitemslist character varying,
  ref_attriblist character varying,
  ref_valuelist character varying,

)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

Comment: With that being said, storing arrays in a column is almost always symptomatic of a design flaw in a database. If you are storing multiple values these almost always belong as multiple rows in a table, not in a single column in a single row.

Comment: Either JSON or Xml

Comment: [@GarethD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048425/garethd) - You could try to store the arrays in a CSV instead of array elements in a single column. On an IBMi AS/400 we would sometimes use temp files/tables to store multiple comma separated values for the life of tables were dependent on the users active jobs

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT A.ORDINAL Ord, A.VALUE Val , B.VALUE Imp 
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('Val 1;Val 2;Val 3;Val 4;Val 5',';',1) A
    LEFT JOIN STRING_SPLIT('Imp 1;Imp 2;Imp 3;Imp 4',';',1) B
    ON A.ordinal=B.ordinal
```

Will return

[image]

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**